# Install doctrine-mongodb-admin-bundle::error:To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-media-bundle, doctrine-mongodb, symfony-flex

I  am using Symfony 3.4 Flex and sonata-admin-bundle": "^3.33" & "php": "^7.0.8"...i want to installing doctrine-mongodb-admin-bundle.when i run

```
php composer.phar require sonata-project/doctrine-mongodb-admin-bundle  3.*@dev
```

I have this error

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

      Problem 1
        - sonata-project/doctrine-mongodb-admin-bundle 3.1.0 requires doctrine/mongodb-odm ^1.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb-odm[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.0.6, 1.0.7, 1.0.8, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.1.5, 1.1.6, 1.1.7, 1.2.0, 1.2.1].
        - sonata-project/doctrine-mongodb-admin-bundle 3.1.1 requires doctrine/mongodb-odm ^1.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb-odm[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.0.6, 1.0.7, 1.0.8, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.1.5, 1.1.6, 1.1.7, 1.2.0, 1.2.1].
        - sonata-project/doctrine-mongodb-admin-bundle 3.x-dev requires doctrine/mongodb-odm ^1.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb-odm[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.0.6, 1.0.7, 1.0.8, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.1.5, 1.1.6, 1.1.7, 1.2.0, 1.2.1].
        - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.2.0 requires doctrine/mongodb ^1.6.1 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.6.1].
        - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.2.1 requires doctrine/mongodb ^1.6.1 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.6.1].
        - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.1.0 requires doctrine/mongodb ~1.3 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 1.6.0, 1.6.1].
        - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.1.1 requires doctrine/mongodb ~1.3 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 1.6.0, 1.6.1].
        - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.1.2 requires doctrine/mongodb ~1.3 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 1.6.0, 1.6.1].
        - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.1.3 requires doctrine/mongodb ~1.3 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 1.6.0, 1.6.1].
        - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.1.4 requires doctrine/mongodb ~1.3 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 1.6.0, 1.6.1].
        - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.1.5 requires doctrine/mongodb ~1.3 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 1.6.0, 1.6.1].
        - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.1.6 requires doctrine/mongodb ~1.3 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 1.6.0, 1.6.1].
        - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.1.7 requires doctrine/mongodb ~1.3 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 1.6.0, 1.6.1].
        - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.0 requires doctrine/mongodb ~1.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 1.6.0, 1.6.1].
        - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.1 requires doctrine/mongodb ~1.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 1.6.0, 1.6.1].
        - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.2 requires doctrine/mongodb ~1.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 1.6.0, 1.6.1].
        - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.3 requires doctrine/mongodb ~1.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 1.6.0, 1.6.1].
        - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.4 requires doctrine/mongodb ~1.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 1.6.0, 1.6.1].
        - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.5 requires doctrine/mongodb ~1.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 1.6.0, 1.6.1].
        - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.6 requires doctrine/mongodb ~1.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 1.6.0, 1.6.1].
        - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.7 requires doctrine/mongodb ~1.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 1.6.0, 1.6.1].
        - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.8 requires doctrine/mongodb ~1.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 1.6.0, 1.6.1].
        - doctrine/mongodb 1.6.1 requires ext-mongo ^1.6.7 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
        - doctrine/mongodb 1.6.0 requires ext-mongo ^1.6.7 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
        - doctrine/mongodb 1.5.0 requires ext-mongo ^1.5 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
        - doctrine/mongodb 1.4.0 requires ext-mongo ^1.5 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
        - doctrine/mongodb 1.3.0 requires ext-mongo ^1.5 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
        - doctrine/mongodb 1.2.2 requires ext-mongo ^1.2.12 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
        - doctrine/mongodb 1.2.1 requires ext-mongo ^1.2.12 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
        - doctrine/mongodb 1.2.0 requires ext-mongo ^1.2.12 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
        - sonata-project/doctrine-mongodb-admin-bundle 3.0.0 requires php ^5.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
        - Installation request for sonata-project/doctrine-mongodb-admin-bundle 3.*@dev -> satisfiable by sonata-project/doctrine-mongodb-admin-bundle[3.0.0, 3.1.0, 3.1.1, 3.x-dev].

      To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
        - C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10\php.ini
      You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

    Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

> I'm going to install media-bundle.To install the media-bundle, i must
>   follow the dependencies.before install media-bundle i must  have
>   installed doctrine-mongodb-admin-bundle [tutorial](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/3-x/doc/reference/installation.html)
>
> I understood this correctly.I have already  **doctrine-orm-admin**.If
>   i want to install **media-bundle** i have to install
>   **doctrine-mongodb-admin-bundle** too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing php extension for mongo, try installing https://github.com/alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter and it should work.

You still need mongo extension installed.

Comment: when i run ::->>$ composer config "platform.ext-mongo" "1.6.16" && composer require alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter
 i have this error :-->Problem 1
    - alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter 1.1.5 requires ext-mongodb ^1.2.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
...... To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10\php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Comment: You still need to install php mongo extension, this is just adapter that makes it work. Do you have extension installed?

Comment: i am not sure.how i can install mongo extension??

Comment: @pedramshabani https://www.phpflow.com/misc/others/mongodb-part-2-install-mopngodb-driver-xampp/ this could help you

Comment: finally I succeeded install extension mongo driver.now i have it on php.info...but again i have that error:-((

Comment: Did you install the adapter? You need extension + adapter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167023/discussion-between-pedram-shabani-and-kunicmarko20).